# How to find Keys with specific member value?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm new in Redis and use Redis 2.8 with StackExchange.Redis Libarary.
**How can I write a `KEYS` pattern to get all keys with specific Hashed member value?**

As I use StackExchange.Redis and want to get Keys with a pattern like this (when username is a member for a key): KEYS `"username:*AAA*"`.

```
database.HashKeys("suggest me a pattern :) ")
```

I will call this method many times on HTTP user request to find out user's session data stored in Redis database, do you suggest a better alternative solution for this approach?

Answer (score 0):

This simply isn't a direct fit for any redis features. You *certainly* shouldn't use `KEYS`  for this - in addition to being expensive (you should prefer `SCAN`, btw), that scans the keys, not the values.